# nginx redirect to a docker container service

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to redirect requests to a service in a different port on a docker container service.

docker-compose.yml

```
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.23.3
        volumes:
          - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          - ./nginx/src:/etc/nginx/html
        depends_on:
          - pinpoint-web
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 81:80
        networks:
          support-network:

    pinpoint-web:
        image: "pinpointdocker/pinpoint-web:${PINPOINT_VERSION}"
        restart: always
        expose:
          - "9997"
        ports:
          - "9997:9997"
          - "8080:8080"
        networks:
          support-network:
```

My Nginx Config:

```
    upstream pinpoint-web {
        server pinpoint-web:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /pinpoint-web {
            rewrite /pinpoint-web/(.*) http://pinpoint-web:8080/$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://pinpoint-web;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error like the following when I try 'http://localhost:81/pinpoint-web', I get this:

```
    {
     "timestamp": 1678301663635,
     "status": 404,
     "error": "Not Found",
     "message": "No message available",
     "path": "/pinpoint-web",
     "data": null
    }
```

Nginx log:

```
2023-03-08 13:54:19 2023/03/08 18:54:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
2023-03-08 13:54:19 2023/03/08 18:54:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2023-03-08 13:54:19 2023/03/08 18:54:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2023-03-08 13:54:19 2023/03/08 18:54:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2023-03-08 13:54:23 172.22.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2023:18:54:23 +0000] "GET /pinpoint-web HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.63" "-"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the request got to the `pinpoint-web` service, but your rewrite rule did not look correct to me. Please change the location to this and try again:

```
location ~ /pinpoint-web/(.*) {
   proxy_pass http://pinpoint-web/$1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help. 

`2023-03-08 15:38:07 2023/03/08 20:38:07 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2023-03-08 15:38:41 2023/03/08 20:38:41 [error] 28#28: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/pinpoint-web" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.23.0.1, server: , request: "GET /pinpoint-web HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:81"
2023-03-08 15:38:41 172.23.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2023:20:38:41 +0000] "GET /pinpoint-web HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.63" "-"
`